# Why is the question title/header a link?

Tags: discussion, questions, hyperlinks

So, you opened this question. If you click on the title of it (e.g. the question header), it basically reloads the page.

Does this serve any purpose? Every browser has a reload-function (F5), why is the title of a question clickable, if it doesn't lead anywhere other than to where you are at the moment?